# Change VBA code with an Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel with a formula `=IF(O10="";"";IF(O9=O10;"";N9-3))` . This formula does not produce a result every time. Sometimes the cells are empty. So I want to copy only the filled cells in another column in order to have them sorted next to eachother. For example

```
N  O  P    R
1  5       1
2  6       4
3  7
4  7  1
5  8
6  9
7  9  4
```

I did it with the following macro

```
Sub Roll2()

Range("R7:R2500").ClearContents
With Range("P7:P2500")    
    .Offset(, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).Copy
    '^--| consider cells with number value resulting from the formula
    .Offset(, 2).PasteSpecial SkipBlanks:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Can I somehow do it without the macro? I have a large workbook, which is built only with excel and I would like to avoid having 5 lines of code if I can.

Comment: You want to copy only the values without a macro in Excel?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what I want

Comment: Copy and then Ctrl+Alt+V (check skip blanks at the bottom of the dialog)

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA and (clearly) you cannot achieve this with a built-in Excel formula then I'm guessing that your post is out of scope for StackOverflow. Maybe this is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($P$7:$P$1353;SMALL(IF(LEN($P$7:$P$1353)>2;ROW($P$7:$P$1353)-ROW($P$6));ROW(14:14));1);"")}
```